# Handle java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException in Intellij IDE on ant input

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

```
<target name="readme" description="Create readme.txt for Build">
        <echo>Creating readme.txt file </echo>
        <input
                message="Enter text for Readme.txt:"
                addproperty="README_TXT"
                defaultvalue="This is for file input: ${ant.project.name}"
        />
        <echo>Text is: ${README_TXT} </echo>
    </target>
```

When executing this,

1. When entered a simple sort string `This is test line` it is working fine
2. When entered a long string like `a,jsha,mskahskakshkahskhakshakskaksdhksdfsfd.,df,d'fdkf;dfdljflkdhfdhkfdkhfkdhfkdkfdkf`

it's throwing **Exception**:

```
/proj1/build.xml:312: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:198)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaInputHandler.readBytes(IdeaInputHandler.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaInputHandler.handleInput(IdeaInputHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Input.execute(Input.java:232)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in IntelliJ IDEA. You're welcome to report it to the issue tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA